# How to experimentally determine the dissociation energy (electronegativity) between identical atoms?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, bond, electronegativity

I was reading on Wikipedia about how [Pauling electronegativities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity#Pauling_electronegativity) are determined through

$$ \vert \chi_\ce{A} - \chi_\ce{B} \vert = \sqrt{E_\mathrm{d}(\ce{AB}) - \frac{E_\mathrm{d}(\ce{AA}) + E_\mathrm{d}(\ce{BB})}{2}}$$

At first, I thought I understood this since for an element like hydrogen the meaning of $E_\mathrm{d}(\ce{HH})$ is clear and easy enough to measure experimentally.

But I don't see how I would do the measurement in general. Do I have to make (unstable) diatoms and then try to measure the dissociation energy very quickly? Even the electronegativity for atoms with $Z > 100$ are known which baffles me. How do they measure these dissociation energies?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I believe the answer is that the element simply needs to bond covalently or metallically with itself when it is in its standard state.  Its standard state doesn't need to be a diatomic.  The metals form metallic bonds.  The metalloids and non-metals (except the noble gases) form covalent bonds.   For instance, carbon's standard state is graphite.   The BDE for the C-C bond would then be the average energy it takes to break apart the C-C bonds in graphite.  Other than the noble gases, I don't know of any elements that don't chemically bond with themselves.